# AutoHotKey: go through a List of Text wirh Key

Tags: autohotkey

I am realy new on ahk.
Is it possible to have a list of text and go trough that list with F12?
A
B
C
If i press F12 show msg Box with A and when i press again F12 it shows B
Is that possible?
Thanks
Skadie

Answer (score 1):

This maybe can give you some ideas..

```
#Persistent
text = A B C
array := StrSplit( text, " " )
Return

F12::
    i++
    if i > array.Count()
        i = 1
    MsgBox % array[i]
Return
```